# I am 13 and looking for a good work

Tags: workout-routines

I am 13 as the title said and I really want to start gaining muscle mass.

Right now I am doing some bike riding and 25 squats 25 jumping jacks and some misc stuff I if I have the time.

I was wonder if there was workout plan that is low cost (remember I am 13) and that I can do at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workout plan that is low cost and can be done at home?**

There are **tons of free calisthenics routines** that can be found over the internet. Here are a few of them :-

[Baristi Beginners Workout](http://baristi-workout.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-calisthenics/)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or [incline pull ups/inverted rows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t97EjUsCFNw).

---> Can't do dips? Do bench dips (either with [foot on the floor](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWBenchDipFloor.html) or [on another bench](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWBenchDip.html)) or more close grip / normal push ups.

[Buff Dude's Punisher Prison BW Workout](http://www.buffdudes.us/blogs/news/25290561-punisher-prison-bodyweight-workout)

---> Can't do one arm push ups? Just do close grip / normal push ups

---> Can't do handstand press? Do [pike push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sposDXWEB0A)

---> Can't do L-Sits? Do [planks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSHjTRCQxIw) or [hanging leg raises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g1hxdkulsE), follow the set and seconds provided

[Fortress Beginners Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-qEE3x27PE)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or incline pull ups

---> Can't do a pistol squat? Do your normal squats

---> Can't do handstand hold? Do [pike push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sposDXWEB0A)

P.S **Can't do regular push ups?** Do [knee push ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BWPushupKnee.html) or [wall push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RtM3L00BUU).

Next, your diet:-

First off, calculate your [TDEE](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/) and **increase your calorie intake by 200~500**(this is known as caloric surplus). Next your protein intake should be **1g per lbs of bodyweight**, where as your fat intake should be around **0.5 ~ 0.6g per lbs of bodyweight** and the remaining can be used to fill up your carb intake, and your micronutrients(aka vitamins and minerals).

However, this is also highly debatable since there is no **right or wrong answers**. By that, what I mean is that you need to adjust your calorie(if necessary) to ensure you are losing weight.

Lastly, do note that it **takes time to either build muscle**. Do not get disheartened when don't see any result in the next few days, weeks, months.